# How to write a query to get a row data between two dates using codeigniter active records?

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

I have below table with date format.

How can I write a query to fetch the records between two dates?

The code I have tried is given below:

```
$this->db->where(array('addeddate >=' => '2017-03-02');
$this->db->where(array('addeddate <=' =>'2017-03-28'));
$this->db->select("sales_commission.*");
$this->db->get("sales_commission");
```

[image: DB Data]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **DATE(addeddate)** in where clause

For Check date condition Use **DATE()**  For **DATETIME** Type Column

Try below script

```
$this->db->select("*");
$this->db->from("sales_commission");
$this->db->where('DATE(addeddate) >=','2017-03-02');
$this->db->where('DATE(addeddate) <=','2017-03-28');
$query = $this->db->get();
if($query->num_rows() > 0){
echo "<pre>";
print_r($query->result());
}else{
echo "No records found!";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to pass as `array`. use `$this->db->where()` like below. The `result_array()` is used to print data in `array` format.

```
$this->db->where('addeddate >=','2017-03-02');
$this->db->where('addeddate <=','2017-03-28');
$this->db->select("*");
$data = $this->db->get("sales_commission");
print_r($data->result_array());//prints records between matched dates
```